# Sharepoint Modern Highlighted Content Web Part KQL Query

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to write a KQL query for a Highlighted Content Web Part to pull events filtered by Category from multiple sites, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I've made the Category column an Indexed Column.  Here's the query I'm trying:

ContentType:Event AND Category:Meeting

This doesn't work.  What am I missing?  Ultimately I would like to pass a parameter through the URL but I can't even get the basic query to work.  What I would like to ultimately have work:

ContentType:Event AND Category:{QueryString.Category}

Is it not possible to query a Choice column?

Comment: I've managed to get the first part of the question figured out as follows...I went into the search settings and looked for the crawled and managed properties.  Ultimately, after some trial and error, the following Managed Property worked: CategoryOWSCHCS.  So my query works as follows

ContentType:Event AND CategoryOWSCHCS:Meeting


However, replacing Meeting with {QueryString.Category} still fails.